# jQuery UI Sortable - disallowing transfer into child elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, children

I'm working with jQuery's UI sortables and have created a system of divs in this format;

```
<div class='mainDiv'>
    <label>text: <input type='text' name='textbox' /></label>

    <div class='children'>
        <div class='mainDiv'>...</div>
        <div class='mainDiv'>...</div>
        <div class='mainDiv'>
            <label>text: <input type='text' name='textbox' /></label>
            <div class='children'>...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The divs can have an infinite number of children, and I want to be able to drag and drop all of the .mainDiv's within their parent box, so I have used this:

```
$(".mainDiv").parent().sortable({items: ".mainDiv", containment: "parent"});
```

However, this allows elements to be dragged into their child or sibling .children divs. which I do not want to happen. I want to restrict elements to staying within their parent.

Any help here would be hot.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve it like this:

```
$(this).parent().sortable({
    items: '> li',
    axis: 'y',
    ...
});
```

In your case, it should work with:

```
items: '> .mainDiv'
```

**containment: "parent"** is not required.

In my case, I enable "sortable" during a previous click event, as it is faster. I think its easier if you bind it to the "mousedown" event. If you create the tree dynamically (e.g.Ajax), I recommend you to use "livequery".

Comment: Thanks man, 6 months later and I can finally fix this :) Luckily the project wasn't vital! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad it was still useful for you. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Joel consider accepting the answer by clicking on the arrow to the left of the main question